# Append to a filename basing upon a pattern

Tags: unix

I have files in Unix like

```
IMG_02052015.txt
IMG_12022015.txt
```

Now i want to rename the files to

```
IMG_02022015_01.txt
```

Can you provide a unix command for this. Itried grep and cut commands, but didnt work.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [`rename(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html):

```
$ rename -n 's/\.txt/_01.txt/' * 
IMG_02052015.txt renamed as IMG_02052015_01.txt
IMG_12022015.txt renamed as IMG_12022015_01.txt
```

---

> Actually the date pattern DDMMYYYY is common

You can use something like this:

```
$ rename -n 's/([0-9]{8})/$1_01/' *
```

You should be able to find a better pattern than `[0-9]{8}` for your date.

Comment: BUt .txt pattern does not come all the time.. Actually the date pattern DDMMYYYY is common. I want to replace this DDMMYYYY with DDMMYYYY_01.